# Uncaught TypeError: count(): Argument #1 ($value) must be of type Countable|array,

Tags: array, null, vistas, php8

Estoy programando una vista

Cuando los datos de la tabla son todos varchar, se muestran muy bien... pero cuando almenos una variable no lo es el arreglo retorna NULL.

$arregloAutores esta retornando NULL, id (int), ident (var),nombre (var)

```
function listar() {
        $comandoSql = "SELECT * FROM tblautor";
        $objControlConexion = new ControlConexion();
        $objControlConexion->abrirBd($GLOBALS['serv'],$GLOBALS['usua'],$GLOBALS['pass'],$GLOBALS['bdat'],$GLOBALS['port']);
        $recordSet = $objControlConexion->ejecutarSelect($comandoSql);
        if (mysqli_num_rows($recordSet) > 0) {
            $arregloAutores = array();
            $i=0;
            while($row = $recordSet->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH)){
                $objAutor=new Autor(0,"","");
                $objAutor->setId($row['id']);
                $objAutor->setIdent($row['ident']);
                $objAutor->setNombre($row['nombre']);
                $arregloAutores[$i]=$objAutor;
                $i++;
            }
        }
        $objControlConexion->cerrarBd();
        return $arregloAutores;
    }
```

En la clase que estoy haciendo el llamado esta así:

```
$objControlAutor=new ControlAutor("");
$arregloAutores=$objControlAutor->listar();

   for($i=0;$i<count($arregloAutores);$i++){
       echo $arregloAutores[$i]->getId();
       echo $arregloAutores[$i]->getIdent();
       echo $arregloAutores[$i]->getNombre();
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Si te fijas, el arreglo `$arregloAutores` lo creas solo cuando `mysqli_num_rows($recordSet)` es **mayor a cero**.

En caso contrario `$arregloAutores` sería una variable `Undefined` pero `return $arregloAutores` sería igual a `null`.

Esto último sería el motivo por el que `count($arregloAutores)` genera el `TypeError`.

#### Solución:

Inicializar `$arregloAutores` fuera del `if (mysqli_num_rows($recordSet) > 0)`

##### Ejemplo:

```php
function listar() {
    // codigo...
    $recordSet = $objControlConexion->ejecutarSelect($comandoSql);
    $arregloAutores = array();
    if (mysqli_num_rows($recordSet) > 0) {

         // resto del código...
    }

    $objControlConexion->cerrarBd();
    return $arregloAutores;
}
```

Comment: Ya lo había hecho así y si bien no me arroja errores el arreglo llega vacío